# Kubuntu never gets to the login screen

Tags: ati, graphics, xorg

I am not sure if Xorg is using the right device... The system in question is an A4-1400 CPU with built-in Radeon Graphics. I added a PCIe Radeon HD 5750, and changed the BIOS so it would use that card automatically. Now it appears that I can see output from the TV plugged into the HDMI port, and boot into recovery mode, but cannot get to a desktop - X doesn't start. It just freezes at the Kubuntu splash screen. I have no idea how to get X to use the proper graphics card.

I pasted the Xorg.log to http://paste.ubuntu.com/6261137/.

And the Xorg.conf generated by `aticonfig --initial` is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/6261161/

Also, see [`lspci`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6261164/) and [`lshw -c display`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6261166/) outputs.

I can provide more information, but something does tell me X is not using the right graphics card and I've no idea where to begin how to fix it... I faced a similar issue before with another distribution but found no information anywhere on how to make X use a specific graphics card. Or maybe it's not that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by installing the Beta drivers instead and activating OpenGL detection from System Settings > Desktop Effects. Now I'm computing in 1080p.